# Laguerre polynomials with integration over entire axis

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, laguerre-polynomials

The [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) are orthogonal with respect to the scalar product
$$
\langle f, g\rangle = \int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) \exp(-x)\,\text{d}x.
$$
Is there a class of polynomials that is orthogonal w.r.t. the integral over the entire axis, i.e.,
$$
\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g(x) \exp(-|x|)\,\text{d}x?
$$
I could certainly create those using Stieltjes procedure, but I'm looking for recurrence coefficients in explicit form.